# SDL SDL_syswm.h fails to compile on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I'm attempting to get some platform specific information from the struct `SDL_SysWMinfo`.

A minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_syswm.h>

void* getWindowHandle(SDL_Window* window)
{
    SDL_SysWMinfo wmi{};
    SDL_VERSION(&wmi.version);

    if (!SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmi)) return nullptr;

    return wmi.info.win.window;
}

int test()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) return 1;

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 50, 50, 1024, 768, 0);

    if (window == nullptr) return 1;
    
    void* windowHandle = getWindowHandle(window);
    
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I get these compile errors:

```
C:\Users\Jarrett\.conan\data\sdl\2.28.2\_\_\package\aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb201f\include\SDL2/SDL_syswm.h(165,18): error C3646: 'hwnd': unknown override specifier (compiling source file C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Test.cpp) [C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\ice_engine.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Jarrett\.conan\data\sdl\2.28.2\_\_\package\aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb201f\include\SDL2/SDL_syswm.h(166,18): error C3646: 'msg': unknown override specifier (compiling source file C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Test.cpp) [C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\ice_engine.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Jarrett\.conan\data\sdl\2.28.2\_\_\package\aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb201f\include\SDL2/SDL_syswm.h(167,20): error C3646: 'wParam': unknown override specifier (compiling source file C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Test.cpp) [C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\ice_engine.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Jarrett\.conan\data\sdl\2.28.2\_\_\package\aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb201f\include\SDL2/SDL_syswm.h(168,20): error C3646: 'lParam': unknown override specifier (compiling source file C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Test.cpp) [C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\ice_engine.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Jarrett\.conan\data\sdl\2.28.2\_\_\package\aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb201f\include\SDL2/SDL_syswm.h(235,18): error C3646: 'window': unknown override specifier (compiling source file C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Test.cpp) [C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\ice_engine.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Jarrett\.conan\data\sdl\2.28.2\_\_\package\aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb201f\include\SDL2/SDL_syswm.h(236,17): error C3646: 'hdc': unknown override specifier (compiling source file C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Test.cpp) [C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\ice_engine.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Test.cpp(11,25): error C2039: 'window': is not a member of 'SDL_SysWMinfo::<unnamed-type-info>::<unnamed-type-win>' [C\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\ice_engine.vcxproj]
```

I can't figure out why I'm seeing this. Including the windows header (i.e. `#include <windows.h>`) doesn't seem to help.

I'm compiling on windows 10 64 bit, using Visual Studio build tools 2022.

Would anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

*Edit*

Here is the compile command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\include /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_hor
         izon\ice_engine\include\scripting\angel_script\debugger /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\include\scripting\angel_script\scriptarray /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\include\
         scripting\angel_script\scriptbuilder /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\include\scripting\angel_script\scriptdictionary /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\include\scripting\ange
         l_script\scripthandle /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\include\scripting\angel_script\scripthelper /IC:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\include\scripting\angel_script\scriptstds
         tring /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /O2 /Ob1 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D AS_USE_STLNAMES /D ICEENGINE_ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING=1 /D FREEIMAGE_LIB /D LIBJPEG_STATIC /D OPJ_STATIC /D LIBRAW_NODLL /D LZMA_API_STATIC /D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D
          HAVE_BZIP2 /D GLEW_STATIC /D BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_NOOP /D BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_WINDBG /D BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_WINDBG_CACHED /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /std:c++17 /Yu"C:/Users/Jarr
         ett/projects/icebreakersentertainment/dark_horizon/cmake-build-relwithdebug/ice_engine/CMakeFiles/ice_engine.dir/RelWithDebInfo/cmake_pch.hxx" /Fp"C:/Users/Jarrett/projects/icebreakersentertainment/dark_horizon/cmake-build-relwithdebug/ice_engine/ice_engine.dir
         /RelWithDebInfo/cmake_pch.pch" /Fo"ice_engine.dir\RelWithDebInfo\\" /Fd"C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\cmake-build-relwithdebug\ice_engine\RelWithDebInfo\ice_engine.pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TP /FI"C:/Users/Jarrett/projects/icebrea
         kersentertainment/dark_horizon/cmake-build-relwithdebug/ice_engine/CMakeFiles/ice_engine.dir/RelWithDebInfo/cmake_pch.hxx" /errorReport:queue  /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/glm/0.9.9.8/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include" /e
         xternal:I "C:/.conan/781bd1/1/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.13/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/libjpeg/9e/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/
         include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/openjpeg/2.5.0/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/openjpeg/2.5.0/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include/openjpeg-2.5" /
         external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/libpng/1.6.40/_/_/package/dabebadc995f5604e23c1a122d0de9c5969f117d/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/libwebp/1.3.1/_/_/package/35e93cf1a4892e74ea68e04ae6584a6768f1a24a/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarr
         ett/.conan/data/openexr/2.5.7/_/_/package/2aa5020d9e2f7b83b0df2e43b910adacd7e9f6a2/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/openexr/2.5.7/_/_/package/2aa5020d9e2f7b83b0df2e43b910adacd7e9f6a2/include/OpenEXR" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/l
         ibraw/0.20.2/_/_/package/a496421bcd1b2d90ac3fda7b0d1d52c7ed44a475/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/lcms/2.14/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/jasper/4.0.0/_/_/package/11ae4
         ebe116abe395eeda38eddb25d52a57ece3c/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/jxrlib/cci.20170615/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/libtiff/4.5.1/_/_/package/1b80e1674bcaf5fcf52e6fe3
         c21071c3f9644ab1/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/libdeflate/1.18/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/xz_utils/5.4.2/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/inclu
         de" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/jbig/20160605/_/_/package/a4e1afe0cdf28a6e8a24a99bcef32c1d8b1b1ea6/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/zstd/1.5.5/_/_/package/bb7459059ccb263b17051f13766d8a54c12f6b46/include" /external:I "C:/.conan/7
         037aa/1/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/assimp/5.0.1/_/_/package/934be063a75bacef3ad4a9af4906ba7a55fc0964/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/irrxml/1.2/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I
         "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/minizip/1.2.11/_/_/package/de4c86e8fcc00fd6629c0ab7fe86105fa6e94c66/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/minizip/1.2.11/_/_/package/de4c86e8fcc00fd6629c0ab7fe86105fa6e94c66/include/minizip" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarre
         tt/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/_/_/package/c9a233d2162940f2b2cb0e76665ffd0126907e8f/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/utfcpp/3.1.2/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/utfcpp/3.1.2/
         _/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include/utf8cpp" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/kuba-zip/0.1.31/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/poly2tri/cci.20130502/_/_/pac
         kage/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/rapidjson/cci.20200410/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/glew/2.1.0/_/_/package/63295b0c0912b8
         2fa79bfbf9508d76264b236b8d/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/vulkan-headers/1.3.243.0/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/vulkan-headers/1.3.243.0/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4
         fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/res/vulkan/registry" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/sdl/2.28.2/_/_/package/aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb201f/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/sdl/2.28.2/_/_/package/aaaec587efc9384b1cddee85ec81c25825cb
         201f/include/SDL2" /external:I "C:/.conan/b5607c/1/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/lua/5.4.6/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/sol2/3.3.0/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0a
         b88f26e3a396351ac9/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/entityx/1.3.0/_/_/package/270dc4a2f77a5fc63ad24b950295fddb3a32f993/include" /external:I "C:/Users/Jarrett/.conan/data/ctpl/0.0.2/icebreakersentertainment/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0a
         b88f26e3a396351ac9/include" C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\icebreakersentertainment\dark_horizon\ice_engine\src\Window.cpp
```

Comment: do you have language extensions disabled? windows.h needs them

Comment: @Raildex I have `set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)` set in my CMake file, however for the actual compile command I don't see `/Za` or `/Ze`.